# Can't decode byte list to string list

Tags: json, python-3.x, decode

In my users variable i store a byte list that i get from a local ldap and convert to a string list with my for loop.
I must return this list as jsonify.
If i don't use that encoding key i get a different output from the original but still encoded.
The problem is i can't access the decode method anywhere.
Any help?

```
users = ldap.get_group_members('ship_crew')

 user_list = []
 for user in users:
     user_list.append((str(user, encoding='utf-8').split(",")[0].split("=")[1]))
 return jsonify(user_list)
```

original list from users variable:

```
[
  "cn=Philip J. Fry,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", 
  "cn=Turanga Leela,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", 
  "cn=Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com"
]
```

for loop with encoded output:

```
[
  "Philip J. Fry", 
  "Turanga Leela", 
  "Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez"
]
```

expected:

```
[
  "Philip J. Fry", 
  "Turanga Leela", 
  "Bender Bending Rodríguez"
]
```

Comment: Why does it need to be byte encoded? The output your are getting is what is expected because `í (0xC3 0xAD)` requires [two bytes of utf-8](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ed/index.htm) (which you are encoding to).

Comment: but i want to get the decoded string "Bender Bending Rodríguez", if i dont put that encoding='utf-8' i get this : Bender Bending Rodr\xc3\xadguez and that is not the original data that i got from my function get_group_members

Comment: It suffices to use user_list.append(str.encode(user).decode('utf-8').split(",")[0].split("=")[1])

Answer (score 0):

I Would use regex to extract your names:

```
import re
l = [
  "cn=Philip J. Fry,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", 
  "cn=Turanga Leela,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", 
  "cn=Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com"
]

NAME_PATTERN = re.compile(r'cn=(.*?),')
result = [NAME_PATTERN.match(s).group(1) for s in l]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Philip J. Fry', 'Turanga Leela', 'Bender Bending Rodríguez']
```

Note that when you dump it to JSON the `í` isn't supported since by default it tries converting to ASCII so it dumps it to UTF-16 (Unicode `0x00ED`):

```
import json
print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  "Philip J. Fry",
  "Turanga Leela",
  "Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez"
]
```

You can get around this via setting `ensure_ascii=False` if you want, though if you are using this in an API I would be careful and stick with ASCII with unicode encodings:

```
print(json.dumps(result, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```
[
  "Philip J. Fry",
  "Turanga Leela",
  "Bender Bending Rodríguez"
]
```

Comment: so when i convert to json the í will always be encoded?

Comment: Unless you tell it not to encode it to ASCII alone. That being said it just looks encoded because you are trying to read the json response. When you load the json or read the string it will automatically print it how you would normally expect it.

Comment: i was trying your code and i get this error TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object when i am returning `NAME_PATTERN = re.compile(r'cn=(.*?),')
    result = [NAME_PATTERN.match(s).group(1) for s in users]` i tried to pass to str with a loop :
    `for user in result:
        user_list.append(str(user))

    return jsonify(user_list)`  but same error

Comment: @PatrickJosé Trying chaning `result = [NAME_PATTERN.match(s).group(1) for s in users]` to `result = [NAME_PATTERN.match(str(s)).group(1) for s in users]`

Comment: another error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Means not all objects in your list have a `cn=...,` You need to make sure they all follow a pattern to use regex,.

Comment: well it's the list on top they all have a `cn=` if i run the code in another project and print it it works, but if i return it as a json it doesn't

Comment: Please add the code you are trying to your question with an input that causes the error. Or put your code in a repl.it that causes the error and share the link. Its hard to help people with vague explanations of the issue they are having.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is correct JSON. Unicode code point 00ED is í, and in JSON any character can be escaped using its Unicode code point. "\00ed" as in your JSON output is a valid way to write that character.

It would also be correct JSON to have that character without encoding it, but apparently jsonify chooses to encode it.

Any competent JSON decoder will then turn it back into a í.

If using the standard library's `json.dumps` you can use `ensure_ascii=False` to prevent this behaviour if you don't want it, but I don't know what "jsonify" is.